# Android trouble parsing HTML

Tags: android, html, parsing, jsoup

This is a simple scenario in which I have tried multiple times but do not receive the data I am after. I am using an imported library called JSoup which parses HTML.

I collect the webpage html document:

```
// url - The URL of the HTML document:
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

From there I know you parse data from tags. I want data inside this tag:

```
<pre>
```

Example scenario:

```
<pre> This is the String data inside this tag I wish to collect </pre>
```

If anyone could help me, I would be grateful (-: 
Thanks all (-:

Comment: What do you mean you don't receive the data? At which point is it failing? Do you at least get a populated document from the `Jsoup.connect(url).get()` call?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should check the source code from the url accessing to confirm whether the tag `pre` exists.
Then, you can use the `select` method of jsoup to extract the `pre` tag. The sample code is like this:

```
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements eles = doc.select("pre");
    for (Element ele : eles) {
        System.out.println(ele.toString());
    }
```